# MasterMind-Resource Leak?

Tags: java

My code is running fine, but every line where I use a scanner it warns me that there is a "Resource leak; 'userGuess' is never closed"  I don't understand what it means and could use some help solving it.  Also if there is anything else in my code worth fixing I could use the help.  Be warned I have a limited knowledge of Java programming.  I also cannot get my TryCounter++ to work...

```
package masterMind2_1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MasterMind2_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("This is MasterMind, a logic game");
            System.out.println("To win you must guess correctly where each number is(The Numbers Range from 1-4)");
            System.out.println("You will be told if you get one correct");
            System.out.println("You will only get 10 tries, then you lose");
            System.out.println("Lets begin");



            //Declare Array
            int [] answerArray;

            answerArray= new int [4];
            //Initialize Array
            //Change these value to change the answers needed to win
            answerArray[0]=2;
            answerArray[1]=3;
            answerArray[2]=2;
            answerArray[3]=2;
//          //Create Board
//          System.out.println("-- -- -- --");



            boolean guessedAll = false;
             int guessedCount=0;
             int tryCounter=0;
             while(tryCounter<9 || !guessedAll){
                 System.out.println("What is the first Number?");
            Scanner userGuess = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num = userGuess.nextInt();
            if (num==answerArray[0]) {
                guessedCount++;
            }
            System.out.println("What is the Second Number?");
            Scanner userGuess1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num1 = userGuess1.nextInt();
            if (num1==answerArray[1]) {
                guessedCount++;
            }           
            System.out.println("What is the Third Number?");
            Scanner userGuess2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num2 = userGuess2.nextInt();
            if (num2==answerArray[2]) {
                guessedCount++;
            } 
            System.out.println("What is the Fourth Number?");
            Scanner userGuess3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num3 = userGuess3.nextInt();
            if (num3==answerArray[3]) {
                guessedCount++;
            } 
            System.out.println("Your guess was "+ num+"  "+num1+"  "+num2+"  "+num3);
            if (num==answerArray[0]) {
                System.out.println("First number was correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("First number was incorrect");
            }
            if (num1==answerArray[1]) {
                System.out.println("Second number was correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Second number was incorrect");
            }
            if (num2==answerArray[2]) {
                System.out.println("Third number was correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Third number was incorrect");
            }
            if (num3==answerArray[3]) {
                System.out.println("Fourth number was correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Fourth number was incorrect");
            }
            if (guessedCount==4) {
                System.out.println("YAY you won!!");
                guessedAll=true;
                tryCounter=10;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try again, except this time don't fail!");
                guessedAll=false;
                tryCounter++;
                guessedCount=0;
            }

            }//What if I collected all of the values first 
        }    //then told them if they were right or Wrong?
             //Black and White Pegs?
             //Fix TryCounter...Why isn't it working
    }
```

Thank you for the Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you never call the [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) method on your Scanner object. A worse problem is that you create multiple Scanners when you only need one.

As for `tryCounter` not working...

```
while(tryCounter<9 || !guessedAll)
```

This will keep looping if either part of the condition is true. My guess is that `!guessedAll` is evaluating to true beyond 9 guesses, so your loop keeps running. You'll need to change the `||` to an `&&` to get it stop looping after 9 tries.  (Also, print out the values of your variables or use a debugger so you can verify that they are changing when you expect them to.)

Comment: Is there an easy way to fix that, or would it be to much of a hassle?

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it in the future so I don't do it again?

Comment: @Zachary Just reuse the same Scanner object by calling `userGuess.nextInt()` again. Don't create another Scanner for subsequent guesses. "Not working" isn't enough of a description to tell me what's going on. What do you expect it to do? What is it doing instead?

Comment: It's not counting like it should... I get past the point where it should have counted and stopped, yet it doesn't stop me...  I want it to stop after 10 passes.

Comment: Thank you I think you solved my problems... I thought that || was or... and I thought && was and...